# Adding UIControl subclass in loadView crashes iphone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm new to iPhone and experimenting with the platform. I have a root view controller which loads it's view from a nib. I accidentally uncommented the `loadView` method in this class, and now the app crashes - is this because if a view controller is initiated from a nib then you can never have a `loadView` implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create your view using a nib file then you should override viewDidLoad and add your subviews there.  You only want to override loadView when you are creating all your views programatically.

Here's a link to the [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController) documentation which has a little bit longer explanation under the entries for loadView and viewDidLoad.

I was confused by the same issue at first...